# Pandas: Faster way to return column value if matching with contents of list?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a dataframes, which contains a list of node values (tuples) such as:

DF1:

```
NAME ,    FROMNODE,    TONODE ,   CHILDREN
V1   ,    (8,9)        (0,1)  ,   [(1,2)]
V2   ,    (0,1)        (1,2)  ,   []
```

In the above example, V2 is a child of V1.

NAME is a string

FROMNODE are tuples

TONODE are tuples

CHILDREN is a list of tuples

I am trying to create a column called PARENTS which would be a list of strings from NAME where the FROMNODE of the present record is matched in the CHILDREN column of another record.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
NAME ,    FROMNODE,    TONODE ,   CHILDREN            ,    PARENTS
V1   ,    (8,9)        (0,1),     [(1,2)]             ,     []
V2   ,    (0,1)        (1,2),     []                  ,     [V1]
```

I tried to do this with list comprehension like so:

```
[[name for name in DF1.NAME if child_node in [node_list for node_list in DF1.CHILDREN]] for child_node in DF1.FROMNODE]
```

This is taking really really long. Is any way I can get the desired result in a faster way?

Edit:

So I feel really silly, I already created a node to node graph using depth first search, and I didn't realize that the graph was bi-directional. I simply applied the same logic I used to find the CHILDREN column onto the PARENTS and this solved the problem in a reasonable timeframe versus trying to have the dataframe build a reference from itself.

Comment: The type of data in these are `tuples` or `strings`?

Comment: They are lists of tuples.

Comment: But in columns `FROMNODE` and `TONODE` just tuples, correct?

Comment: Yes, I clarified the question. Sorry about the vagueness.

Comment: In the example you gave, this doesn't seem to match what you are asking for as V1 is a parent of V2 but the FROMNODE in v2 `(0,1)` is _not_ in the children of V1 `[(1,2)]`... can you please update or am I missing something?